# Automorphism group of a simple graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I am trying to understand an exercise in Bondy and Murty's book "Graph Theory with Applications".  The exercise is as follows:

"Consider the permutation group $\Lambda$ with elements $(1)(2)(3)$, $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$.  Show that there is no simple graph $G$ with vertex set ${1,2,3}$ such that $\Gamma(G)=\Lambda$"

Here $\Gamma(G)$ means the automorphism group of $G$.

I don't see how to start this proof.

> Edit:
>
> It looks like this question is a duplicate of a question posted last year:
>
> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000292/221021

Comment: If you have no idea at all, you can always try a brute force approach with such a small graph on $3$ vertices. This means: write down all simple graphs on $3$ vertices and find their associated automorphism groups. You will see that the group from the execise is not one of them. And, thus, the exercise is proved.

Comment: I'm thinking there must be some way to produce a contradiction, but it hasn't occurred to me yet.  Moritz method will work.  If I can think of anything else I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess the thing that confused me is that $\Lambda$ is a group and it maps $K_{3}$ to itself so I thought $\Lambda$ was an automorphism group of $K_{3}$.  However, $\Lambda$ is a subgroup of $S_{3}$ which maps $K_{3}$ to itself.  So does an automorphism group have to include all the permutations which map $G$ to itself?  The definition given by Bondy and Murty does not make this clear: "An automorphism of a graph is an isomorphism of the graph onto itself."  I am trying to learn group theory at the same time :-)

Comment: Here is a definition for the automorphism group of a graph from Graphs and Digraphs 5th edition:  "The set of ALL automorphisms under composition forms a group, called the automorphism group of G".

Comment: Thank you.  I will check out Graphs and Digraphs.

Comment: If you are learning group theory at the same time check out "A Course in Group Theory" by J. Humphreys (ISBN-10: 0198534590)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is **not** an answer to your question but only for your pleasure: this graph on $9$ vertices has $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$ as its automorphism group.

Comment: This is a nice solution to the next part of the exercise:

"Find a simple graph $G$ such that $\Gamma(G)\cong\Lambda$"

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is my attempt at a "more formal" proof.  Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be the vertices of the graph $G$ of order 3.  Since $(123)$ and $(132)$ are automorphisms of this graph and since isomorphisms preserve edges, we have that $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_1 \in E(G)$ which implies that $G=C_3$.  However, $\Gamma (C_3) = \{(1)(2)(3),(123),(132),(12),(23),(13)\} \neq \Lambda$, a contradiction.  Thus, there can be no such graph $G$.

Edit:
As pointed out by curiosity, this does not work.  However, my argument partially stands.  Let's fix it.
Starting at my third sentence in the original attempt:Since $(123)$ and $(132)$ are automorphisms of this graph and since isomorphisms preserve edges, we have that $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_1 \in E(G)$ OR $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_1 \notin E(G)$.  Thus, we have two options.  Either $G = C_3$  OR $G=\overline C_3$ (the empty graph on 3 vertices).  In both cases,  $\Gamma (C_3) = \Gamma (\overline C_3)= \{(1)(2)(3),(123),(132),(12),(23),(13)\} \neq \Lambda$, a contradiction.

Comment: What about the simple graph with $3$ vertices and no edges: then, $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ are also its automorphisms (among others) and it does not follow that this graph has any specific edges.

Comment: Good point.  I was making a leap of faith there without really thinking it through... should i delete my answer?  I see no way to "fix" my answer without just deleting it.

Comment: No, never delete your answer. If nothing comes to mind, let it just rest for a time. That often gives me a fresh perspective.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my argument works now.

Comment: I offer the following: The given permutations imply that the associated simple graph on $3$ vertices must be vertex-transitive, that is, all vertices have the same vertex degree. The only possible graphs on $3$ vertices are $K^3$ and its complement. A graph and its complement always have the same automorphism group. Since $K^3$ has $S_3$ as automorphism group, it follows that the sought-after graph on $3$ vertices with $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$ as automorphism group cannot exist.